# How to add downarrow above matrix in the right position?

Tags: matrices, arrows

I am trying to add \downarrow to align with the second matrix shown below, so that the columns are aligned.
Any idea how to achieve this?

```
$$a_{11} =
\begin{array}{c}
\rightarrow \\
\\
\\
\end{array}
    \begin{bmatrix}
  & 1 & 3  \\
  & 2 & 6   \\
  & 5 & -4  \\
\end{bmatrix}
 \cdot  
\begin{array}{ccc}
\downarrow & & \\
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 4 & -1 \\
 -1 & 3 & 2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
 = 1 \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot (-1) = 2 -3 = -1$$
```

The above code is formatted to:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

A quick hack:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
a_{11} =
\begin{array}{c}
\rightarrow \\
\\
\\
\end{array}
\begin{bmatrix}
  & 1 & 3  \\
  & 2 & 6   \\
  & 5 & -4  \\
\end{bmatrix}
 \cdot  
\begin{array}{l}
\quad\hspace{-1pt}\downarrow\\  %%<-----
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 4 & -1 \\
 -1 & 3 & 2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
= 1 \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot (-1) = 2 -3 = -1
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[a_{11} = 
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col]
\rightarrow & 1 & 3 \\
            & 2 & 6 \\
            & 5 & -4 
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row]
\downarrow \\
2 & 4 & -1 \\
-1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
=1\cdot2+3\cdot(-1)=2-3=-1\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Tnx, this is extremely helpful

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\[
a_{11} =
\begin{blockarray}{r@{\enspace }[rr]}
\rightarrow &\bigstrut[t] 1 & 3 \\
  & 2 & 6 \\
  & 5 & -4 \\
\end{blockarray}
 \cdot
\begin{blockarray}{crr}
\enspace \downarrow\\ %%<-----
\begin{block}{[rrr]}
    2 & 4 & -1 \\
 -1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
= 1 \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot (-1) = 2 - 3 = -1
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]